# Can I map coarse and fine tempo control to a single MIDI controller in Ableton Live?

Tags: midi, ableton-live

One of the nice features of Ableton Live is its quick MIDI mappings. I can enter MIDI map mode and quickly assign an interface element to a knob or slider on a MIDI controller.

I am trying to map Live's global tempo control to a MIDI knob. When I enter MIDI map mode, the tempo control looks like this:

[image: Screen-crop of Live's tempo section in MIDI map mode]

The left and right sides of the tempo are "coarse" and "fine" control, respectively, and are mapped separately. I can clearly assign a knob to each one, but I would like to use one knob to control them both. Ideally, I could sweep between several coarse positions, and the fine control would update to catch the positions in between.

I feel like I've missed something. Is this arrangement possible? It would be conceptually simpler to have one "tempo" knob to deal with, instead of having to manage two of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up discovering the answer by accident. If you map only the left-hand portion of the tempo (the coarse control), the fine control sweeps to match.

I have mapped the left-hand side to a knob and can confirm that I can have finer-than-integer tempo resolution, which is the intended behavior.

Comment: Yeah, I've found that it just depends on the range for what you set the controller to.  The smaller the range, the more fine control.